# Excel VBA Macro Resizing the Plot Area

Tags: excel, vba, plot, resize, area

Using 10 pixel borders for chart area.
Resized chart area to exactly cover selected cell range without overlapping cells on left and right side.
Trying to resize plot area horizontally to fit into resized chart area.

Trying to say:

1. chart area width = chart area width - 2x border weight
2. plot area width = resized chart area inside width

Any way to do this? Something like:

```
Chart.PlotArea.Width = (.ChartArea.Width - 2*.ChartArea.Border.Weight`)
```

Comment: Well did you try that?  What happened?

Comment: What is the exact error message displayed when the VBA code does not work? Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.